# Bash script cannot expand environment variable despite trying several different approaches

Tags: bash, centos, python

I have a bash script I'm running with `sudo` that is supposed to call three other bash scripts. Two of the scripts that are called run fine. One of them, however, attempts to call a python script. The path to this python script is given in the script as `SCRITPS_URI="${HFGEO_HOME}/bin/waveform.py."` My problem is that despite trying many different approaches, I can't make the third script properly expand `$HFGEO_HOME.` I have tried:

exporting it

running with `sudo -E bash -c`

running `sudo HFGEO_HOME=/data/hfgeo/ ./script.sh`
https://askubuntu.com/questions/57915/environment-variables-when-run-with-sudo

adding it to my `~/.bashrc` and my `~/.bash_profile`

Running `sudo visudo` and adding it to my defaults `env_keep`
https://askubuntu.com/questions/57915/environment-variables-when-run-with-sudo (Second to last answer)

I keep getting the error `python: can't open file '/bin/waveform.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory` I have confirmed that the file is where it is supposed to be. In my `bashrc` and `bash_profile` files I am exporting the variable as:

`export HFGEO_HOME=/data/hfgeo`

and then add it to my PATH variable as

`export PATH=${PATH}:${HFGEO_HOME}/bin`

What's bugging me is that the system I'm trying to set up is running on the same OS, albeit a newer version, as another machine I have where this script works just fine. The original machine is running CentOS 6.4 and the machine I am having this problem on is running on CentOS 6.9. I did not have to do any of the above to get this script to work on the 6.4 machine. I've already tried fixing this myself and some of the above attempts I made were based on my research, but none of them seemed to fix my problem. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What if you replace `script.sh` with `env`? i.e. `sudo HFGEO_HOME=/data/hfgeo/ env` => Does `HFGEO_HOME` appear in the output?

Comment: `sudo env VARIABLE=value cmd`.

Comment: Can you post the full script?

Comment: Double-check if it's really defined as  `SCRITPS_URI`?

Comment: I tried the above two solutions from @Kusalananda and @xhienne but no luck. It is really defined as `SCRITPS_URI` I double checked

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried executing the script from inside of a sub-shell? Something like this should work:

```bsh
sudo bash -c 'export HFGEO_HOME=/data/hfgeo/; ./script.sh'
```

It would help if you posted the script that you're trying to run, or preferably a minimal example that produces the same error.